fingerstyle vs alternate picking speed, which one is the fastest?
With fingerstyle vs alternate picking guitar techniques, in terms of raw speed, which one can be the fastest?

Measured in notes played per second? Strumming all six strings up and down. You can hardly go any faster than that. (Okay, patting them all at once is even faster, but very limited in terms of volume.)

The fastest picking is done by the fastest picker - whatever technique works for them is what works for them. The literally fastest picking is almost certainly machine-assisted.

I find it a bit of a non-consequential question, hence the dv.

It depends upon a variety of factors and components.
The skill of the guitar player.
The experience of the player.
The fidelity of the equipment measuring "speed".
In the end, it all comes down to the requirements of the performance.
What does the song require?
Speed without beauty, grace, and audience appreciation is just noise.
Slowness without melody, coherence, and listener appreciation is just boring.
My advice?
Work on your fingerstyle and your alternate picking techniques.
And everything else.
Become a versatile and adaptable player.
Melodic, and pleasing to the audience's ear.
Make that your goal.
Not just some nebulous notion of speed.

For most people alternative picking is way faster. I'd be shocked if a guitarist or bassist can tremolo-pick with two fingers faster than they can with a pick. I've seen even classical guitarists tremolo-pick with a single finger using both upstrokes and downstrokes like a pick, probably because tremolo picking with two fingers is pretty difficult, and even the thee-finger technique taught in classical guitar is pretty easy to mess up.
Good players will pull off a good tremolo fingerstyle, but the pick makes it that much easier. Some people will want you dead if you don't use the right technique, so, for your safety, please learn the right technique for any piece you might perform in public. All jokes aside, all techniques will come in handy if you practice them. Sometimes you don't have a pick, sometimes it's too cold to move your fingers fast enough... It's good to be versatile, especially if you're into improv.

I think it depends on what you want. Tremolo with a pick or a single finger can go quite fast, but I think it is hard to get consistency and a lot of volume at such speed. Also due to momentum it will always require movement of the hand, making it very hard to play other notes at the same time. On the other hand if you look at otherworldly guitarists like this: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=DjOQ69JjTRo&t=733s I don’t think this would work at such speeds with a single finger tremolo or a pick.

@Lazy Of course fingers are your only option if you're playing a classical arrangement where you need your thumb to be playing the bassline, and/or other fingers to play harmony. However, since the question is specifically about raw speed, and having learned both techniques, I feel fairly confident saying that for the same amount of training hours, you will be faster using the pick (including at advanced levels). Of course there's plenty of nuance we could go into, but OP is not a interested in that, at least given his phrasing of the question.
